# If the product of two numbers is equal to one of the numbers in the column then return the value from the level column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need two excel formulas: for V level and for R level.

Based on the product of numbers a and b, numbers 1-25 are obtained, which are classified into 5 levels (1-5).

The first formula should return the V level of numbers 1-5 based on the product of classified numbers 1-25.

The second formula should return the R level of the numbers I, II, III, IV, V along with the corresponding color.

[image]

I tried with the excel formulas: VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH, and some other combinations but it doesn't work.

**Edit**: What I've tried so far:

```
=INDEX(D18:D22;MATCH(C5*D5;H18:H22;0))
=VLOOKUP(C5:D5;D18:H22;5;FALSE)
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5*D5;D18:D22;0));VLOOKUP(C5*D5;D18:H22;5;FALSE))
```

Comment: How did you try to use those function? Show us the code that you tried and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: A formula cannot read the color of a cell, nor can it return it.  If the cells are colored with conditional formatting you will need to apply the same rule to the output.

Comment: I tried with this: 

=INDEX(D18:D22;MATCH(C5*D5;H18:H22;0))

=VLOOKUP(C5:D5;D18:H22;5;FALSE)

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5*D5;D18:D22;0));VLOOKUP(C5*D5;D18:H22;5;FALSE))

I'm sorry, I'll take the rule to the uotput for conditional formating.

Answer (score 0):

**First option:**

Bojan, you can solve this like below with `index` and `vlookup`.
In order to use `vlookup`, first you need to spread your legend table like I did in below screenshot.

C9: `=INDEX(D3:H7,B4,E1)`

C10: `=VLOOKUP(C9,$C$12:$D$25,2,FALSE)`

H9: `=INDEX(D3:H7,C10,H1)`

H10: `=VLOOKUP(H9,$C$12:$E$25,3,FALSE)`

Orange cells need your manual input.

[image]

**Second option (after your comment):**

After adding below built-in function into a module of your excel file, you will not need the legend table for calculation.  Just call your built-in function to get your levels.

```
Function get_level(levelType As String, value As Integer) As String

If levelType = "V" Then
Select Case value
Case 1, 2
    get_level = "1"
Case 3, 4, 5
    get_level = "2"
Case 6, 8, 9
    get_level = "3"
Case 10, 12, 15, 16
    get_level = "4"
Case 20, 25
    get_level = "5"
End Select

ElseIf levelType = "R" Then
Select Case value
Case 1, 2
    get_level = "I"
Case 3, 4, 5
    get_level = "II"
Case 6, 8, 9
    get_level = "III"
Case 10, 12, 15, 16
    get_level = "IV"
Case 20, 25
    get_level = "V"
End Select
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Ozgun, thanks a lot!

But I tried to use the existing tables in my project, so as not to add a new one, simplified like you. Is it possible to reach such a solution - a formula (which is a little bit complicated)? :)

Comment: A built-in function may help, in which you will pass your V value and get your V level in return.  Is it possible for you to add a function to your workbook.  You need to save your file as xlsm.

Comment: Just added a second option into my answer.

Comment: Thanks once again, Ozgun. So, if that don't possible with formula than I'll try that second option.